# APNS string not found for loc-key when string resides in Framework's Localizable.strings file

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am developing a framework to be used in other iOS apps. A major part of this framework is receiving push notifications. The framework is localized in English, Spanish, German, Italian, and French. The .strings files are in the resources directory of the framework as Localizable.strings. When the app is in the foreground all localizations work correctly and the various strings are found and translated. However when I receive a push notification via APNS containing the "loc-key" : "NOTIFY_UPLOAD_SUCCESS_BODY" key, the notification is displayed with the string "NOTIFY_UPLOAD_SUCCESS_BODY" instead of the value which should be "The file was uploaded successfully.". My assumption is the key cannot be found because the key resides in the framework bundle and not the app's bundle. Is there anyway to get around this to where these notification strings can reside in the framework like the other localized strings in the app?

Comment: Are you in debug or release scheme? How are you testing this - simulator or device? Is the device configured correctly? The framework bundle should have been copied into the app at build time so that shouldn't be an issue. Make sure your file path's to the framework are good to make sure that it is copied in while building.

Comment: I am using a Debug scheme with a sandbox push cert, testing on a real physical device. The device receives notifications correctly assuming I hard code the key values. The framework is copied correctly because all other framework functionality is available in the app.

Comment: Hi @AlexC.have you found solution to this issue? If the localisation files are added to the app, the OS correctly localises the push notification, since it looks into the main bundle